# Did I just prove $h^{-1}(W)$ is open in $X$?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $h:X \rightarrow Y$ be a function between topological spaces. Let $U$ be a closed subset of $X$ and $g=h|_{U}$ be the restriction. Suppose further that $g$ is continuous. Let $W$ be open in $Y$.

Then $g^{-1}(W)$ is open in $U$, since $g$ is continuous. So $g^{-1}(W)=V \cap U$ for some $V$ open in $X$.

But, correct me if I'm wrong here, we have $g^{-1}(W)=h^{-1}(W) \cap U$, right? If so, then I conclude that $h^{-1}(W)$ is open in $X$.

$g^{-1}(W)=h^{-1}(W) \cap U$. Proof:

If $x \in g^{-1}(W)$ then $x \in U$ and $h(x) \in h(W)$, therefore $x \in h^{-1}(W) \cap U$.

Otherwise, if $x \in h^{-1}(W) \cap U$, then $x \in U$ and so $g(x)$ makes sense and $g(x) \in W$, since $g=h$ on $U$, thus $x \in g^{-1}(W)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the issue is that you can have $g^{-1}(W) = h^{-1}(W)\cap U$ without $h^{-1}(W)$ being an open set even if the intersection is open in $U$.

For example, set $X=\mathbb{R}$, $U=[0,2]$.

Then $[0,1)= [-1,1) \cap [0,2]$ is an open subset of $[0,2]$ in the relative topology, since we can write $[0,1) = (-1,1)\cap [0,2]$, but $[-1,1)$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$.